# Record Count before Running Query - C#

Tags: c#, sql

All,

I need some help. I have a windows form application I have been building, it executes some sql queries based upon a group radio box entry selected. I noticed some "slowness" when it runs a large set so wanted to 1) prompt the user and 2) warn them on the following count.

Here is what I have. Any suggestions for improvements:

```
if(rdbDate.Checked)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from TABLE where ORDER_DATE between @mindate and @maxdate", myConnection);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mindate", dtFromDate.Value.Date);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxdate", dtToDate.Value.Date);


            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(t);
            if(t.Rows.Count>10000)
            {
                DialogResult msgresult = MessageBox.Show("Warning your query returned " 
                    + t.Rows.Count + 
                    " are you sure you want to continue?", 
                    "Question", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                if (msgresult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    return;
                }

            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
        }
```

I would need to repeat this for each radio button. 
I also think that its executing the query to get the count? I would prefer to do the select count(*) and then run the query if possible?

Thanks in advance

Xathras

Comment: It executes the query and fills the dataset before you know the count. So by the time you are warning them, it is too late. You should do as you guessed - run select count(*) first, then fill the dataset if they want to continue.

Comment: do you have any recommendations or links to where this is done? Thanks for replying Keith

Comment: You should consider pagination and/or filtering. It's hard to see anyone wanting to trawl through thousands of rows in a gridview.

Comment: Dean, one of the purposes of this app is to provide them access to the data to query and output results to CSV/Excel. I have that, but the data grid is about showing the results. Obviously I want to look at how I can warn the users when they do something with results they might not expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of records and prompt the user:

```
if(rdbDate.Checked)
{
    int numberOfRecords;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from TABLE where ORDER_DATE between @mindate and @maxdate", myConnection)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mindate", dtFromDate.Value.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxdate", dtToDate.Value.Date);

        numberOfRecords = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    if(numberOfRecords >10000)
    {
        DialogResult msgresult = MessageBox.Show("Warning your query returned " 
            + t.Rows.Count + 
            " are you sure you want to continue?", 
            "Question", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (msgresult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
     }

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from TABLE where ORDER_DATE between @mindate and @maxdate", myConnection);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mindate", dtFromDate.Value.Date);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxdate", dtToDate.Value.Date);


    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(t);
}
```

Because the counting of rows is not executed inside of a serializable transaction with the filling of the dataset, it is conceivable that the record count could be different than the number of rows in the dataset - if the data was being inserted at the same time, for instance. But this is probably not something that you need to code for if the use case treats this like a batch operation.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I will give that a bash this morning. But looks great.. :-)